# How to update to SDK 24.0.2

Tags: java, android, kotlin

SDK Platforms
[image]

SDK Tools
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even update to the latest by changing the build tool in build.gradle file, but as you said you are pretty new and firstly just want to run this project by installing the build tool version `24.0.2`

Please click on `Show Package Detail` of your second screenshot then you will start seeing all the other build tool version you can install and you will find your 24.0.2 as well like I started seeing that after selecting the `Show Package Detail`.

[image]

Comment: The project can be opened but can NOT be run now. What to do now? Pls see the last attached picture in the above question.

Comment: I think you got everything figured out as i can see you already accepted an answer. 

Comment: I accepted the answer because the previous problem is solved but new problem shows and I slightly modify my question. Do you know how to solve this new situation?

Comment: Pls see the last picture I attached above in the question.

Comment: can you try again and see what is the log you are getting

Comment: The green triangle run button is grey so I can NOT run it and I got these red messages from Event Log
`Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (41 s 341 ms)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232504/discussion-between-dinkar-kumar-and-lisa-baron).

Comment: This is out of scope for this question as you changed the detail of the question after accepting the answer, if you have some different issue, see if there is an answer for your new problem already present in StackOverflow or not and if you are not able to find one then you can create a new question with the new issue you are facing

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools > SDK Manager`.

1. Make sure Android SDK Location matches your `local.properties` file `sdk.dir` value. (Fix it in the file if required)
2. In the SDK Platforms tab, check an install `Android 7`.
3. In the SDK Tools tab check and install `24.0.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your instruction (1) (2) are checked. As you can see the attached pic. I don't have 24.0.2 so what do I do?

Comment: Try checking `Show package details` in the right bottom corner of the window.

Comment: The project can be opened but can NOT be run now. What to do now? Pls see the last attached picture in the above question.

Comment: Is hard to tell... Try syncing the project with the gradle files (an elephant icon button), also clean and build.

Comment: The green triangle run button is grey so I can NOT run it and I got these red messages from Event Log
`Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (41 s 341 ms)`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have internet connection and build the project again.
On the main menu click Build > Make Project

Comment: I can NOT Make Project because the drop down Build menu selection "Make Project" is grey and that is probably due to my `failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.2` problem.

Comment: do you have internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I do have internet connection.

Comment: under SDK Tools, check 'show package details' box, locate 24.0.2 on the list and check its box then click 'apply'  and follow screen prompts to install it